# Why bootstrap validation not Empty and string length is not working in my login form?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Admin Login</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.4 -->
<link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
<link href="assets/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Theme style -->
<link href="assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- iCheck -->
<link href="assets/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- BootstrapValidator css and js -->
<link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrapValidator.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]-->
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/respond.min.js"></script>


<!--  [endif]-->
</head>

<body style="background-color:#D2D6DE">
<div class="container-fluid" >
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="login-page" >
            <div class="login-box">
                  <div class="login-logo">
                    <a href="#"><b>Admin Login</b></a>
                  </div><!-- /.login-logo -->
            <div class="login-box-body">
                   <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
              <form id="loginForm" action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                      <div class='form-group'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="UserName EmailId" name="username" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
                      </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">    
                          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-md">Cancel</button>                        
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md">Sign In</button>
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div>
              </form>
                   <a href="ForgotPassword.jsp">I forgot my password</a><br>
                   <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a>

          </div><!-- /.login-box-body -->
        </div><!-- /.login-box -->
        </div>
     </div>   
</div>
</div>
    <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.2 JS -->
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#LoginForm').bootstrapValidator({
             message: 'This value is not valid',
             fields:{
                 username:{
                     message:'The username is not valid',

                     validators:{
                         notEmpty:{
                             message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                         },

                         stringLength: {
                                min: 6,
                                max: 30,
                                message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                            }
                     }

                 }

             }

          });
      });
    </script>
```

This is my simple login form with bootstrap validation in jsp.But my bootstrap validation is  not working at all.  What is the problem? Also suggest me some sites or demo to learn bootsrap validation.